# German limited visa - how many days I can stay outside EU

Tags: visa, germany

I have Aufenthaltserlaubnis and because of some personal reasons, I have stayed outside Germany (and EU) for more than 160 days.

I would like to enquire how many days I can stay out of Germany, in my visa category? Is it 180 days in a year (with multiple entries) or 6 months on a stretch, once you leave Germany?

This year, I have already stayed 160 days in total in my home country (outside EU), with multiple entries. So, do I need to enter Germany before 179th day? Or since I came to my home country on 20th August 2019, so I can stay for 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

If you are out of Germany at a stretch for more than 180 days, your card becomes invalid i.e(180days+1day) or if you de-register from Germany your card becomes invalid immediately. This is what I have been told.
And with EU blue card its one year.

Comment: this is not true in cases (as with @Anony) where the residence permit is issued based the spouses permit. In the case a BlueCard. See https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19213/aufenhaltstitel-validity-after-staying-away-from-germany-for-more-than-a-year and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19226/aufenhaltstitel-validity/19227#19227

Comment: Also note, that the 180 day period can be extended   if reported beforhand. See my original answer.

Comment: I agree if the foreign office is informed beforehand and you get a letter from them then longer absence is allowed and your permit stays valid.

Comment: I would suggest you upvote my answer and delete yours that is partially based on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what type of residence permit you have, hard to say.

You should inform the issuing authority of your intention of leaving for a longer period beforehand.

Based on the specific situation, leave can be granted for a longer period than 6 months.

If you have given your work and flat and deregistered, the residence permit becomes invalid upon exit.