# Aufenhaltstitel validity after staying away from Germany for more than a year?

Tags: visa, germany

I went to consulate in my home country and they said since my husband is a EU BlueCard holder and I have not been de registered from Germany I can travel with my aufenhaltstitel and it remains valid. My husband is locally employed in Germany and I am planning to join him and therefore went to apply for the Fanily Reunion Visa but was sent back saying my visa is valid and we cannot issue you a schengen visa when you already have a valid visa. And they also said I can very much travel on that visa. Now my question is will i be stopped at the airport? What if they say that my visa is no more valid? Will they know I was out of Germany for more than a year?

---

```
Art des Titels 
  Aufenthaltserlaubnis 
Anmerkung
  30
```

---

Comment: Which kind of *Aufenthaltstitel* do you hold?

Comment: Its valid till 2020. But how to know the type? Its a dependant permit as long as my husband is in germany i can stay and work over there...that is all i know?

Comment: Its a plastic card

Comment: What do the fields *Art des Titels* and *Anmerkungen* say? Update your question and quote them in verbatim, please.

Comment: Art des titels aufenthaltserlaubnis and anmerkungen in the next line it says 30

Comment: That 30 refers to *§ 30 AufenthG: Ehegattennachzug zu Ausländern*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plastic card telling you

---

```
Art des Titels 
  Aufenthaltserlaubnis 
Anmerkung
  30
```

---

already **is** the »Family Reunion Visa« you asked the German consulate for.

That *30* in the *Anmerkungen* field refers to [§ 30 AufenthG: Ehegattennachzug zu Ausländern](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__30.html).

Im am inclined to believe the German consulate. They are the official agency. As I understand it, this *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* stays valid until the expiration date as long as your husband does not leave **Germany** at the same time as you for more than 6 months, or for a job **outside Germany**. Caveat: in the latter case, both your husband's and your *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* becomes invalid **immediately**. Take care.

You can move to, from and inside the Schengen zone freely with that card.

Comment: So there will not be any problem even if I was out of Germany for more than an year and my husband switching to a blucard (he had a aufenhaltstitel before and changed to a blu card this august). I can travel with the card now?

Comment: My childs visa says its valid till 6-10-19 as her old passport was expiring on that date but now she has her new passport. Also in the footnote it is mentioned titel valid till october 2020...will it be okay if we travel on 5th october and reachgermany on 5th oct itself?

Comment: The important part is this is a dependent *Aufenthaltserlaubnis*. If your husband applied for a *BlueCard EU* that's okay, but if he picks up work e.g. in France, your German *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* is invalid on the very same day. You had to apply in France for a familiy reunion visa again.

Comment: No he is based in germany only. He is locally employed in Germany.

Comment: And please clarify my doubts regarding my childs visa as well

Comment: It's not possible to get your *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* extended in short time. It takes several weeks at least. You can enter the Schengen zone at Oct 5th, but had to leave on the very same day. Otherwise you can be deported. The only way to get around that is getting an appointment on Oct 5th (or before) at the local *Ausländerbehörde* in the city in Germany where your husband lives and they will issue a *Duldung* on the spot, until the regular *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* is processed. But you have to get that appointment **now**.

Comment: But in the footnote it says titel valid till 17-10-2020....they even told us verbally that once she gets her new passport her visa will be valid till 2020. But again will they stop us from entering germany or should i prepone my trip? Kindly help

Comment: So if it says titel valid till 17-10-2020 so is it okay if we travel on 5th october or a later date is fine as well?

Comment: We don't separate children from their mother over here. It's pretty obvious your daughter lives on your and your husband's expenses, and that's where *gesunder Menschenverstand* is the guideline of German officials, including police and border patrol.

Comment: Yes but if they say her visa is valid until 6th october and dont allow her....will they send us back? Even if its written titel valid till 17-10-2020 in the footnote...what if my home country creates a problem with that?

Comment: As long it is put somewhere on the document, there is no doubt at all. And if it wasn't, the officials would pretty certainly also issue a *Duldung* on the spot to fix that, as you as the accompaning mother have a valid *Aufenthaltserlaubnis*.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places that your visa will be checked when you fly to Germany.

The definitive check is when you enter the Schengen area (either in Germany, or somewhere else if you don't fly direct to Germany).  That check will be performed by trained immigration officials. Although they may well know that you have been out of the country for a year, they are very unlikely to give a different answer than the German consulate in your country.

The other check is when you board the plane.  The airline will get fined if you are rejected at the border, so they will check your documents very carefully. There have been suggestions that airlines will sometimes reject documentation that would have been accepted at the border.  However *they* will definitely have no way to tell how long you have been out of country, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Will they deport me if their views are different from the consulate office of my country. Like they might say I have been out of Germany for more than a year and now my card becomes invalid. Although we have not yet been deregistered from Germany.

Comment: @Anony Technically I don't think they will deport you - they will just refuse you entry to Germany, and require the airline to take you back to your home country.  This is *always* technically possible, but it is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Since your residence permit is based on your husband's permit, the rule about a residence permit becoming invalid after a long absence does **not** apply.

Only if your husband left for a specific time would both be effected.

Your residence permit was issued so that you can be with your husband

- it does not require you to be there all the time

That is why the Cousulate stated that your residence permit is still valid.

The residence permit itself will probably contain the following

- **Art des Titels**: Familiennachzug

or

- **Art des Titels**: Aufenthaltserlaubnis

  - § 29 Familiennachzug
  - § 30 Ehegattennachzug
  - § 32 Kindernachzug

with 1 or more of the above text in the **Anmerkungen** field

with that the Border Control will know that you are just returning.
Airlines *should* know this as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my husband held an aufenhaltstitel earlier and then he applied for an EU BlueCard this August. But I and my child have not yet been de registered from Germany. He was out of Germany for a few months but was never de registered and was back in germany before 180 days. So i am a bit confused whether my residence card remains valid or not? The consulate office is not ready to listen to me...all they said is you can travel on this visa but I am somehow very unsure.

Comment: @Anony what does text shown after **Anmerkungen** say? That is what is important.

Comment: It just says anmerkungen and in the next line its written 30 after that pass details n validity and also in the last line it says erwerbstatigkeit gestattet and for my child after anmerkungen its written in the next line 32 abs nr 1

Comment: @Anony sorry, my mistake: **Art des Titels** discribes the type.

Comment: Aufenthaltserlaubnis for both my n my child

Comment: @Anony **§ 32 AufenthG Kindernachzug**,  so this is based on a existing permit from your husband. This is fine.

Comment: Will there be any problem with us entering Germany?

Comment: But my husband changed his card from aufenhaltstitel to a blue card...that will not be an issue I guess?

Comment: And also one more question since my daughters old passport was valid till october 2019 so they issued her permit till october 19 but told us that once she gets her new passport her visa will be valid till 2020 but now she has her new visa and the in the card it says titel valid till october 20 in the footnote but otherwise it says valid till october 19. Will it be okay if we travel after october or should we travel before the date mentioned in her visa?

Comment: @Anony none of this should be a problem, both your husband's changed permit nor for the children. After arrival just get everything updated for the children.

Comment: Thank you....i will not be stopped at the airport for my childs visa then...and thanks for answering all my questions so patiently :)

Comment: @Anony if you are satisfied, then accept the answer.

Comment: How can i accept the answer?

Comment: And one more question my childs visa shows 6th october as valid date although in the footnote it says titel valid till oct 2020...is it okay if i travel on 5th october and reach germany on 5th october itself?

Comment: @Anony Yes any day before expiration is fine. When you ask a question, voting for a answer (click on the up arrow above number  at the top of the answer) will accept the answer. A geen checkmark should show up.

Answer (score 0):

If the German consulate in your home country says your card is valid, then that should be true. There is no valid reason for the consulate to mislead you, as eventually this could create more work for them.

EU law regulates the validity of TCN residence cards and German authorities may have the right to de-register you ***but they don't have to***. Simply leaving for more than 6 month does not invalidate such documents. Border guards also should only have access to your entry-exit records of their specific country. They also don't have the right to question the judgement of the issuing authority and it would mean they'd have to examine all entry- and exit-stamps in your passport. In case of a new passport, they wouldn't even be able to do that.

The [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32016R0399) does not seem to suggest anything of the contrary. The right of entry with a valid residence card is not restricted by your absence there. The rules laid out in that document regarding refusal of entry also IMHO do not appear to give border guards any rights to make decisions on the validity of residence permits.

Comment: Yes but will they allow me once I reach Germany? Because they can say my aufenhaltstitel is now invalid since i was away from Germany for more than a year? What then? Is there any possibility of them denying me entry? Or my home country passport control denying me to depart?

Comment: Who do you mean with "they"? Didn't you say the German consulate says your document is valid? The Borders code doesn't give border guards the right to revoke your visa.

Comment: They means border control....those who check when you enter a country first...your passport n visa....german consulate in my home country said the visa is valid...and my daughters visa is valid till 06-10-19 and the title is valid till oct 2020 because her oldpassport expires on 06-10-19 although she has a new passport issued now . And we are travelling on 5th october.

Comment: @Anony As I said, border control cannot "revoke" a visa or make a decision on its validity. The residence card is equivalent to a visa according to Schengen Rules. If you're talking about one person only, then a visa in addition to the residence permit should be irrelevant.

Comment: @Anony you probably should delete you duplicate post btw

Comment: What does visa in addition the residence permit mean...i and my daughter both have the residence card? The only thing is her card says gultis big 06-09-2019 but in the foot note it says titel valid till 17-10-2020...as her old passport will expire on 06-10-19 but she has her new passport now.

Comment: @Anony ah... ok... you didn't really make that clear before. My personal opinion says it doesn't matter if you enter on the 5th. Did you tell the German consulate that you plan to travel on the 5th? Once the card expires, I can imagine problems with airlines and possibly (not so much though) non-German border control. Reading the EU directive, it should the permit that counts not the card. Also it seems card validity is gradually loosened. ID cards of EU citizens are already valid beyond expiry. Anyway, I can only suggest you talk to the Consulate again. Tell them every details---slowly.

Comment: We are non EU citizens....the ggerman consulate is not answering any further questios.

Comment: @Anony you probably could try again with the embassy, another consulate or the foreign ministry... if it was a telephone call, you could see confirmation by email. Being non-EU citizen is unlikely a reason not to answer questions. From your posts and comments here, however, I get the feeling that much of your communication mishap is related to the way you approach people. It is possible that the German consulate does not even understand what you want from them. Perhaps you should ask a lawyer to get the answers you seek.

Answer (score 0):

New update from Frankfurt Foreign office auslanderbehorde.

They say my situation is a bit tricky. What the border control will say we dont know. They might or might not let you enter. Chances of refusing entry is very high. Travel is going to be a huge risk, the only point to my advantage is the mail from the visa department of German consulate of my home country wherein I am told that I can travel on this visa. But then there are instances when the border control just refuses you entry even when you have a valid visa. And I guess the rule that as long as my husband is in germany my visa stays valid is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask an Ausländerbehörde, who issued your residence permit, to confirm its validity. If they do not answer per mail, ask your husband to go there. This should be the right way, cause consulate only issues visa, and not resident permit. Probably the consulate cannot decide on the validity of the residence permit, but Ausländerbehörde kann issue an official paper LIKE [this one](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324921/) which will be enough to clarify all border control issues.