# Aufenhaltstitel validity

Tags: visa, germany

Is my aufenhaltstitel still valid if my husband changed his employer and switched to EU blucard. Although my husbands previous employer didnt de register him and didnt cancel his aufenhaltstitel as well. And also even if I have not been de registered from germany but my address is showing unknown. What does that mean? Is my aufenhaltstitel still valid? Have I been de registered or is it that they are unable to find my address and hence showing unknown? I have been away from germany for more than a year but the consulate in my home country say my visa is valid. But now I got to know this? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

You already asked this question here:

[Aufenhaltstitel validity after staying away from Germany for more than a year?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19218/17166)

and **extensive** answers were given.
Such questions should only be asked once.

Comment: But i got to know today that my address is showing unknown currently. Does that mean I have been de registered?

Comment: @Anony the Cousulate told you the Aufenthaltstitel is still valid. Where are you seeing **address unknown**. Only you can de-register your residence, mnot the employer.

Comment: Even if the relocation agency takes care of the visa and all the formalities? Sorry but I just want to be sure about everything.

Comment: My husband asked while registering himself and they said for us they can see address unknown thats why...

Comment: @Anony sorry, but you are adding information here, as in the other question. You have a valid visa. After return go to registration office and check and register again if needed.

Comment: Yes becoz my husband changed city. So we are not registered in the new city. Thats y i was asking. Right now our address is unknown..so i am not sure if i was deregistered or not.

Comment: @Anony most likely you were deregistered togeather with your husband when he moved. Apon return register at the new address and everything will be fine.

Comment: How can my visa be valid if i am de registered?

Comment: @Anony Registration tells them **where** in Germany you live (Residence). A Residence Permit **allows** you to stay in Germany. 2 different processes. When you return to Germany, you register your new address.